# Weird visual parasites in Atom-editor

Tags: atom-editor

Under Atom 1.23.3 x64, I can see some visual parasites (see picture below), like vertical blue lines. It happens whatever the file format (.py, .tex, .txt...).

I'm under linux Debian Buster/Sid.

Edit : this "thing" apparition seems to be randomness and purely visual, i.e., it's impossible to select and inspect it. It lies in between two caracters. It will move if I zoom in or out, but always be somewhere, as noise.

[image]

Comment: Hit Ctrl+Shift+i and inspect that thing, just like you would do it in Chromium/Chrome. Maybe you can deliver us more information which element is causing this and it probably will be easier to help you.

Comment: @Fusseldieb Hi, this "thing" apparition seems to be randomness and purely visual, i.e., it's impossible to select and inspect it. It lies in between two caracters. It will move if I zoom in or out, but always be somewhere, as noise.

Comment: Oh, then I suggest that you issue a bug report: https://atom.io/packages/bug-report You can try changing your video drivers as a test to see if the bug disappears, after that maybe disabling hardware acceleration on Atom or Linux itself to see if it's related to that, but now we are going faar to offtopic. Try asking on http://superuser.com (It's StackExchange too)